# Can I create two object instances that contain different methods

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I completely understand the concept of prototype inheritance in JavaScript if the methods in the constructor are the same for all instances. But what if I want to create objects via constructors but want the methods to produce a different result for each instance?

```
   function Player (health, power, stamina) { 
       this.health = health;
       this.power = power;
       this.stamina = stamina;
       this.recovery = function () {
        
       return this.health += 20;

       }
   }

    var hulk = new Person ( 100,80,60 );
    var superman = new Person ( 100,70,50);
```

My problem here is I want hulks recovery to add 20 when I call the recovery method but I want superman’s to add 40. If I add the method to the prototype instead of directly into the object I still want that method to be only for the hulk and a different one for superman. Do I create object literals for this and specify the different methods for each object?  This seems long wielded if I had hundreds of characters! Or do I add another multiple methods to the Person prototype even if it’s only going to be used by one instance? What’s the best way to make superman’s recovery better than the hulks whilst still using a constructor ? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a 4th parameter to `Player`, one which indicates health regen:

```
function Player(health, power, stamina, healthRegen) {
   this.health = health;
   this.power = power;
   this.stamina = stamina;
   this.healthRegen = healthRegen;
   this.recovery = function() {
     return this.health += this.healthRegen;
   }
}
var hulk = new Person(100, 80, 60, 20);
var superman = new Person(100, 70, 50, 40);
```

If *most* characters had a particular amount of health regen (say, 20), and you only wanted `superman` and a couple others to have different health regen, you could use a default parameter to avoid having to write `20` so much:

```
function Player(health, power, stamina, healthRegen = 20) {
   this.health = health;
   this.power = power;
   this.stamina = stamina;
   this.healthRegen = healthRegen;
   this.recovery = function() {
     return this.health += this.healthRegen;
   }
}
var hulk = new Person(100, 80, 60);
var superman = new Person(100, 70, 50, 40);
var normalPerson = new Person(50, 50 50);
```

Above, see how you only need to pass the 4th parameter when the desired health regen is *other* than 20; otherwise, it'll default to 20.

Comment: Whilst I have you here mate. What if I want certain methods available to some instances and not available to others? How would I go about dealing with that? Thanks again

Comment: Depends a bit on the type of method. You could create a subclass which extends the parent class, or you could pass another boolean parameter to the constructor (like what was done with `healthRegen` above) which checks whether the method can be run on that object or not..

Comment: Can I create the methods within the constructor and just only ever call them on the instance that I want to use it on? This doesn’t seem right though?

Comment: I'd put methods on the prototype instead, and check if the instance is permitted to call the method inside that method. `sing() { if (this.canSing) { console.log(this.name + ' is singing'); }}`

Comment: Perfect but how can I check if they are permitted to use the method if the Person prototype is available to all instances? My understanding is all instances can access all methods within the constructor or prototype?

Comment: Assigning the boolean to a property of the instance in the constructor. `constructor(canSing = false) { this.canSing = canSing; }` Then just check that property when the method is called. (throw an error if not permitted, if you want.) Or only define the property on a subclass, eg `class PlayerWhoSings {`